# Plot a function with specific list of values and use manipulate

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, functions, manipulate, plot-themes

I have the following function:

```
T[r_, theta_] := Cos[theta*\[Pi]/180]*r^2
```

which I would like to evaluate using predefined values of r from a function which I define as:

```
logspace[a_, b_, n_] := 10.0^Range[a, b, (b - a)/(n - 1)]
```

therefore I define my r values as:

```
rlist = logspace[Log10[1], Log10[10000], 100]
```

If I do not have the "theta" (or angle) option in the original function, I will just evaluate and plot the function like this:

```
ListPlot[T /@ rlist]
```

My question is then, how can I do the same thing but also when having different values for "theta"? I would like to use the function Plot (instead of ListPlot) so that I can also use "Manipulate" to play with the parameter "theta" and see how the function changes. I know that Manipulate and Plot always needs the following syntax:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {n, 1, 20}]
```

but in my case, here x is already defined from my logspace function.

I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: do you get what you need with `Manipulate[Plot[T[x, r], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {r, rlist}]`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I want to evaluate T[r,theta] with the values from rlist, and then interactively vary theta. Therefore, according to what you suggest then it should be something like this: Manipulate[Plot[Temp[r, x], {r, rlist}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}] but this does not work.

Comment: Use `Manipulate[Plot[T[r, x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {r, rlist}]`. you can't use `{r, rlist}` as plot range.

Comment: this is exactly what I do not understand. I do not want to use {r,rlist} as a plot range, I just want to evaluate the function T for my own values of r from rlist. Then, use theta from 0,2Pi interactively with Manipulate.

Comment: @lorz If you look closer at the bracket scoping in the suggestion by @beny, you can see that `{r, rlist}` there is specified for `Manipulate` rather than `Plot`.